# Virtualize Wireshark with Thinstall from Vmware

Tags: wireshark, vmware-thinapp

Has anyone been able to virtualize Wireshark and PCAP utilizing thinstall from VMWare without requiring installation of the PCAP on the main OS?

Comment: Hmmm... it's similar to boxedapp....

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way VMWare Thinstall or [ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/) work,
it is not likely you will get the full Wireshark functionality.

If you **can** install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/about.html) [**within the ThinApp**](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1260282),
you may get the *deep inspection* ability of the tool,
But, will not be able to tap any communication not normally reaching the ThinApp system.
For example communications of the native OS with the network.